# How to do 3Dmaps and Offline map in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, dictionary

I am looking for 3d maps & offline maps data download 
examples in Android.

If you know any example please post here regarding 3d maps and Offline maps.

Is there any 3d map example in Android?
here is the code what i am using  https://github.com/nutiteq/hellomap3d

I am getting error  in console

```
     [2012-11-26 16:15:40 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/nutiteq/MapView$1;
     [2012-11-26 16:15:40 - HelloMap3DActivity] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/nutiteq/MapView$1;
```

[image]

Comment: k.. @WebnetMobile.com but u voted down.. do u know must i tried for this.. after my research, if i don't get answer then i am using this satckoverflow.. please don,t vote down.. If u know answer Please say me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the solution for above answer..

just remove nutiteq-3dsdk-1.0.0pre.jar file Its working fine..